# jquery loop function until variable set

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that loops every 30 seconds until the server returns "done". Once that happens, I want it to stop the loop, but I can't get it to stop.

I was trying to use

```
success: function(data) {
    var test_function = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process.php?query",
            data:form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (data != "done") {
                    Loading();
                    $("#results").html(data);
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"process.php?finished",
                        data:form.serialize(),
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#results").html(data);
                            Done();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };
    var refreshInterval = 5 * 1000;
    setInterval(test_function, refreshInterval);
}
```

The setInterval works as intended in terms of looping, but I can't get it to stop (The "success:" is at the end of another ajax call). (I don't have what I've tried in the code, but I tried clearInterval a few times). My guess is either the way I'm looping it, or the amount of ajax calls I'm using is my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My God... Ajax inside an Ajax inside an Ajax..That's like the 'inception' of Ajax!

Comment: Check out the [clearInterval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval); this is what it's for.

Comment: That looks hinky, why do you have check if it's finished, then do another call etc. just send whatever you need to send and return when it's done ?

Comment: Well, the way it works is when the user clicks the button, it places the data in a text file, and a python program grabs the data, runs a search, and puts the resulting data in a database. Then, using ajax, I search to see if there are any updates in the database, and to see if the python program has finished (via a text file that says "done"). It's a bit overcomplicated, but mixing ajax and python is new to my coworker and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is more robust. Try this:

```
success: function (data) {

    var refreshInterval = 5 * 1000,
        isDone = false;

    (function test_function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "process.php?query",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data){

                if (!isDone) {

                    Loading();
                    $("#results").html(data);

                } else {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "process.php?finished",
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        success: function (data){

                            isDone = true;

                            $("#results").html(data);
                            Done();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });

        if (!isDone) {
            setTimeout(test_function, refreshInterval)
        }

    })();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the order of your code, the serInterval would continue even after the if condition for 'done' is satisfied

I've added a variable refresh to keep the state of whether it is done and if refresh is needed.
Try running this:

```
success: function(data) {
  var refresh = true;
  var test_function = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process.php?query",
        data:form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data != "done") {
                Loading();
                $("#results").html(data);

   } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"process.php?finished",
                    data:form.serialize(),
                    success: function(data){
                        refresh = false;
                        $("#results").html(data);
                        Done();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
 };

 if (refresh){
 var refreshInterval = 5 * 1000;
 setInterval(test_function, refreshInterval);
 }
}
```